# How to check the validation of a field of each objects contained in a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset of "Match". In "Match" model there is a boolean field and I'd like to check if this field is equal to True for each objects contained in my queryset. How can I do this ?

```
matches = Match.objects.filter(phase=phase)
```

**`models.py`**

```
class Match(models.Model):
    isFinished  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team1Win    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team2Win    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phase       = models.ForeignKey(Phase, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teams       = models.ManyToManyField(Team, default=None, blank=True)
```

The field in question is **`isFinished`**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily with checking if there are any instance with `isFinished=False`. If such instances doesn't exist, so all have `isFinished=True`:

```
Match.objects.filter(phase=phase,isFinished=False).exists()
```

Previous statement return `True` if you have any `isFinished=False` in your queryset and `False` if all your `Matchs` are with `isFinished=True`.

Comment: more optimized :)